# Adding map marker api

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I added mapmarker via mapkit but I will pull latitude longitude via api. When I write to add the api I get multiple errors.

```
struct MapAnnotationsView: View {
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))

let placeArray: [Place] = [Place(title: "Deprem Test", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.8008, longitude: 27.2465))]

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray)
        .onAppear {
                        Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
                            self.quakes = quakes
                        }
                    }
    { annotation in
        // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
            // This is your custom view
            AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Code error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m547p.png)

Comment: No, the questions are not the same, I couldn't add the mapmarker there, they helped. I added it. But there was a problem while adding api here, I wrote it.

Comment: The `onAppear` and its closure have to go *after* the `{ annotation in ... }` closure, since the latter has to be attached to `Map`. You also have to create a `@State` variable called `quakes`. I'm not sure what type it should be, since you haven't included `Api`.

Comment: `@State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = [] ` I added it as but my 1st and 2nd problem is not solved.

Comment: I was typing in the wrong parentheses, I tried a bottom bracket and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onAppear` and its closure have to go after the `{ annotation in ... }` closure, since the latter has to be attached to `Map`.

```
struct MapAnnotationsView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9520281, longitude: 35.6980142), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 30, longitudeDelta: 10))
    @State var quakes: [EarthQuake] = []
    
    
    let placeArray: [Place] = [Place(title: "Deprem Test", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.8008, longitude: 27.2465))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: placeArray)
        { annotation in
            // This makes a generic annotation that takes a View
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate) {
                // This is your custom view
                AnnotationView(placeName: annotation.title)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Api().getEarthQuake { (quakes) in
                self.quakes = quakes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By doing it this way, my error went away, but I could not pull the mapmarkers from the api.

Comment: You haven't included `Api` in the question, so there's no way to know what the issue would be. I suggest you start a new question with that in mind, since I've addressed all of the issues in the current question as presented.